# what is the way to check the credentials with the single browser no need to close and open new browser until loop stop

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
@Test
public void TestSetup()  throws IOException, BiffException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\UAT WEBSHOP.xls");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    s = w.getSheet("Regro");

    for(int row=1; row <=2 ; row++)
    {
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http:/path/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String username = s.getCell(2,row).getContents();
        System.out.println("***********************************");
        System.out.println("Username: "+username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_username_leftAside")).sendKeys(username);
        String password= s.getCell(3,row).getContents();
        System.out.println("Password: "+password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_password_leftAside")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[@class=' js opacity generatedcontent pointerevents']/body[@class='page-homepage pageType-ContentPage template-pages-layout-RexelHomePageLayout pageLabel-homepage language-de ']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='content-top-inner']/div[@id='content-inner']/div[@class='mid-wrapper'][1]/div[@class='yCmsContentSlot']/div[@class='login clear']/form[@id='loginForm']/div[@class='left sign-in']/button[@class='Sign-in rx-btn mb0']")).click();

        try
        {
            if((driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div"))).isDisplayed())
            {
                System.out.println("Login Failed");
                String Error=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div")).getText();
                System.out.println("The Error mesaage is :"+Error);
                System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************************");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Login Sucessfull");
            System.out.println("***********************************");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-inner']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[9]/a")).click();
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

While executing this script every time browser opens and enter the credentials and will close if its fail or pass.But i need is once the browser is opened check with the first credential if pass logout and then try with next credential.If failed enter the next credential and continue.So that time consuming to open the browser driver will be reduced i believe. Please help me how to exactly make changes in this code as i am beginner please elaborate the steps

Comment: If you don't want it to close, then why are you telling it to close?

Comment: Create the driver object once before the loop, and take the close out of the loop and put it after the loop finishes it's iterations.

Comment: Your code is basically telling it to close and reopen a new driver instance for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are after.  Your current code is telling it to close and reopen a new driver instance.  This will open one driver instance and keep it open for the longevity of the for loop, then close it after the iterations of the loop is done.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();

for(int row=1; row <=2 ; row++)
{
    ...
}

driver.close();
```